# How to make a alert when a particular permission is used by other apps in android?

Tags: java, android

I want to continuously monitor all apps for the permissions they are using.

If a particular permission which I specified is used by any of android apps on the same device, my app should show an alert dialog about it.

How to do that ?

Answer (score 1):

This is not generally possible. Your app cannot find out when another app is accessing contacts, requesting location updates, or most other things secured by platform permissions. Your app also cannot find out when another app is doing things that may be secured by custom permissions defined by yet other applications.

Comment: is that possible at-least in rooted android device when my app is granted with root access?

Comment: @KarthikeyanS: Not that I am aware of. Root is not some magic bullet that solves all problems. The only certain way to do what you want would involve creating your own ROM mod, where either you bake into the ROM mod the "alert the user" feature that you seek, or you bake into the ROM mod some API that allows apps to spy on other apps' secured behaviors.